# Modifying attributes from within custom element inside React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, custom-element

I have a [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements) being used inside React. I want to be able to change attributes on the element from React. I also want to be able to change the same attributes from inside the element itself. Unfortunately, when the element changes its own attribute, this causes some odd side effects that I believe are related to React's virtual DOM being unaware that the attribute has changed.

To illustrate, assume we have a React render function that returns the following:

```
<my-component foo="bar"/>
```

And `my-component` has logic inside of it that, when the element is clicked, will change `foo`'s value from `bar` to `unicorn`. Everything up to this point works as expected. The problem is that during the next render cycle, `foo` is not set back to `bar`. I *want* `foo` to be set back to `bar`.

My guess is that React's virtual DOM has `bar` as the cached value (it doesn't realize it has changed to `unicorn`) and therefore doesn't attempt to set it back to `bar`.

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. How do I make it so `foo`'s value is set back to `bar` on the next render cycle?

Comment: React won't touch `<my-component>` if there is no change in attributes or children.

Comment: custom elements need to be real-only to play well with react, or you can have the element use React's update cycle (1-way), or something like redux. in short, don't change HTML without React.

Comment: Sounds like you have bar hard coded ( `foo="bar"` is hard coded ) somewhere? Maybe consider an architecture framework behind react to run and manage the state. I personally like Redux.

Comment: @NguyễnĐăngKhoa: generally, that's true, but if react decides that a large replacement is more efficient than many small updates, "unchanged" elements _can_ be replaced. app code should be written to work in either case...

Comment: @ajmajmajma I don't actually have `bar` hard-coded. It's just for illustration. In reality, `bar` is coming from Redux.

Comment: @dandavis thanks. I don't understand React internal that much.

Comment: ah, ok. well the web-component (I'm guessing) doesn't fire anything in redux, so the state is going to stay the same. My guess is you'd need to maybe pass a redux action in too that fires the update.

Comment: @ajmajmajma Right. In my case, I basically want to ignore `foo` being set to `unicorn` and overwrite it back to `bar` on the next render. From the answers, it sounds like there's not really a way to "force-write" an attribute value and instead I'll need to make the custom element never update its own attribute.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. You could possibly check the component lifecycle and force the prop to whatever. However it seems a bit weird because react re-renders every time do you fire *any* action, so if you touch something else on the ui it will set back to bar.

Comment: Even if I send the value of `bar` back to the custom element, the value doesn't get past the virtual DOM (I assume the virtual DOM thinks the value hasn't changed). I know the concept of forcing the value back to `bar` seems weird, but I was looking for alternatives before modifying the custom element. Thanks for the help all.

Comment: also be aware that custom elements will only really work well in Chrome, or Firefox with the "Web Components" config flag on. using the two common  registerElement polyfills, the VDOM will compare empty custom tags, rather than ones populated after creationCallback is fired...

Comment: Interesting @dandavis. We're using the custom-elements polyfill from Polymer. It seems to be rendering changes okay. Maybe it's running inefficiently though?

Comment: @Aaronius: yes, it will render fine, but if you set a log in createCallback, you'll probably see it firing more often than expected on un-customized browsers outside of chrome. it's not the end of the world, just keep it cheap to run and don't deeply nest web components.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the virtual DOM. To make it behave the way you want, the custom element needs to be written in a way that supports it.

Think of this as being equivalent to [controlling an `<input>`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), where you would bind a handler to the input's `onChange` and either call `event.preventDefault()` to block any changes to the vlaue, or pass the new value back to the `<input>` to update the virtual DOM.

Therefore for this to work, the custom element needs to support a similar event handler.